# Any way to hide inline option from Firefox's addon preferences?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

After adding some in-line options as described in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Inline_Options I'm curious if there is a way to hide only one such option from the addon preferences. I'd like to manage the preference contents through other chrome.

Ideally I'd like to keep the other preferences as they are without resorting to a custom preferences window.

Comment: what does this mean? "I'd like to manage the preference contents through other chrome."

Comment: what does this mean? "Ideally I'd like to keep the other preferences as they are without resorting to a custom preferences window."

Comment: can you please rephrase your question? it's very unclear.

Comment: For example via a button in the browser bar with its own popup menu

Answer (score 0):

Yes you set or remove the `hidden` attribute on the `setting` tag.

See here for examples of how to play with inline options dom on run time:

- https://github.com/Noitidart/WorkspaceHopper/blob/92a3e494cebb72518736e93ab0a20c2fdeb76df7/resources/workspacehopper/lib/main.js#L42
- https://github.com/Noitidart/Throbber-Restored/blob/442c8642a5ba9281357ec34ed687c616bf942d1e/bootstrap.js#L97

Comment: The "hidden" attribute sounds familiar. Sadly my tests indicate it not working with inline options statically defined in an options.xul file. Other attributes documented in Mozilla's inline article do have an impact on the display.

Comment: That's odd it should work. Worst case scenario you can do `style="display:none !important;"`

Comment: Ironically I discovered "style" worked during another web search and came to the same conclusion. My tests show it works. Thanks.